# How find sub-string(0,91) from long string?

Tags: c#

I write this program in c#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i;
    string ss = "fc7600109177";           

    // I want to found (0,91) in ss string 


    for (i=0; i<= ss.Length; i++)
        if (((char)ss[i] == '0') && (((char)ss[i+1] + (char)ss[i+2]) == "91" ))
            Console.WriteLine(" found");
    }
```

What's wrong in this program and how can I find `(0,91)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't have to cast to `char` your `ss[i]` or others. `ss[i]` and others are already `char`.

As a second, you try to concatanate two char (`ss[i+1]` and `ss[i+2]`) in your if loop and after you check equality with a `string`. This is wrong. Change it to;

```
if ( (ss[i] == '0') && (ss[i + 1] == '9') && (ss[i + 2]) == '1') 
   Console.WriteLine("found");
```

As a third, which I think the most important, **don't write code like that**. You can easly use [`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) method which does exactly what you want.

> Returns a value indicating whether the specified String object occurs
>   within this string.

```
string ss = "fc7600109177"; 
bool found = ss.Contains("091");
```

Here a <kbd>[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/D2RVHQ)</kbd>.

> use "contain" return only true or false and "index of" return location
>   of string but I want to find location of "091" in ss and if "091"
>   repeat like: ss ="763091d44a0914" how can I find second "091" ??

Here how you can find all indexes in your string;

```
string chars = "091";
string ss = "763091d44a0914";
List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
foreach ( Match match in Regex.Matches(ss, chars) )
{
     indexes.Add(match.Index);
}

for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Count; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0}. match in index {1}", i+1, indexes[i]);
}
```

Output will be;

```
1. match in index: 3
2. match in index: 10
```

Here a <kbd>[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/KswuUf)</kbd>.

Comment: use contain return only true or fulse

Comment: @ZainabJawad So..? Isn't that you want?

Comment: use "contain" return only true or false

 and "index of" return location of string
 
but I want to find  location of "091" in ss and if "091" repeat like:

  ss ="763091d44a0914" 

how can I find second "091" ??

Comment: @ZainabJawad Updated my question. Take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.Contains()` for this purpose

```
if(ss.Contains("091"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(" found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know where "091" starts in the string then you can use:

```
var pos = ss.IndexOf("091")
```